# How to remove text after drawInRect?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have a UIView subclass called BackgroundText to draw some text.

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [@"synchronized." drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 29, 320, 60) withFont:bigFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation alignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
}
```

--

```
backgroundText = [[MMRoomBackgroundText alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake (0, 142 + 44, 320, 80)];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundText];
```

I expect     `[backgroundText removeFromSuperview];` can remove these text from screen,but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view and check.

Comment: You mean after I called `[backgroundText removeFromSuperview];`?
Tried but failed.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you.

Here ***LoadingBG is My View*** And ***LoadingText is My Label*** And I am Putting Text in Label and Add Label into View and After that I remove View From SuperView When I dont Need Text.

**For Adding Text:**

```
UIView * LoadingBG = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
UILabel *LoadingText = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)] autorelease];
LoadingText.text = @"Loading...";
LoadingText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[LoadingBG addSubview:LoadingText];
```

**For Remove Text:**

```
[LoadingBG removeFromSuperview];
```

And Here I had Use Fixed Size For View And Label. You can Use What You want as a frame.

Comment: It might because that I init a new backgroundText every time I need it.
After put the init code at viewDidLoad,it works.

Thanks Bapu and Abdullah